# Is there an idiomatic way to establish a dictionary with the variable name as the key and value as the value?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there an idiomatic (more pythonic, perhaps) way to handle this:

```
title = "my title"
name = "my name"
# [... on and on ...]

my_dict = {
    'title': title,
    'name': name,
    # and on and on
}
```

Basically, have the variable name (as coded) be the key and the variable value be the value?

Comment: There isn't a more idiomatic way, no. There are *hacks* that let you do it *faster*, but they are *hacks*.

Comment: something other than `dict(title=title, name=name)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, objects don't have a name, nor do they know their name. Thus, given `title`, you cannot deduce the string `"title"`.

The scope (`globals`, `locals`, `vars`) associates *names* to *objects*, so any such hack has to go through the scope. One way of doing that is:

```
title = "my title"
name = "my name"

things_I_want = "title", "name"
scope = vars()
{name: scope[name] for name in things_I_want}
#>>> {'title': 'my title', 'name': 'my name'}
```

This is, of course, frowned upon. The correct way of doing this is the long way.

Comment: Going through `itemgetter()` is really heavy: `{var_name: vars()[var_name] for var_name in things_I_want}` is way more legible, because it is as direct as it can be.

Comment: @EOL I agree; I've changed to your method. I was maybe just overthinking this a bit too much.

Answer (score 4):

The real question is, why create the variables in the first place?

Instead of starting out with `title = "my title"` just create the dictionary and use the keys (`my_dict["title"] = "my title"`).